# Text getting overlapped in uitableview cells in iOS swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I have created a prototype `UITableViewCell` on storyboard.It contains 1 ImageView, 3 labels to display the content. All the controls have outlets in corresponding subclass of `UITableViewCell`. I display messages which can be multi line. So I had to add following methods

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
```

The text of the labels is getting overlapped and it happens whenever I scroll the tableview. It is only happening with either first 2 rows or the last row.But as i searched on google, I found that it can happen on any row any time. Here's my code of the extension which is commonly written.

```
extension ConversationViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if let count = selectedConversation?.msgArrayWithBodyText.count {
            return count
        }
        return 0
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(conversationMessageIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ConversationMessageTableViewCell
        let currMsg =  selectedConversation.msgArrayWithBodyText[indexPath.row]
        cell.userFullNameLabel.text = currMsg.senderName
        cell.dateLabel.text = selectedConversation.getShortDateForMessage(currMsg.timeSent)
        cell.messageBodyLabel.text = currMsg.bodyText //Constants.testString

        let imageUrl = "\(Constants.serverUrl)/api/users/\(currMsg.senderId)/profilePicture"
        if let item = ImageCache.sharedInstance.objectForKey(imageUrl) as? CacheableItem {
            print("\(imageUrl) found in cache, expiresAt: \(item.expiresAt)")
            cell.userImageView.image = UIImage(data: item)
        } else {
            cell.userImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Profile")

            self.imageDownLoadingQueue.addOperationWithBlock({
                if let url = NSURL(string: imageUrl) {
                    if let purgableData = NSPurgeableData(contentsOfURL: url) {
                        if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: purgableData) {
                            print("cache: \(imageUrl)")

                            let item = CacheableItem()
                            item.setData(purgableData)
                            ImageCache.sharedInstance.setObject(item, forKey: imageUrl)

                            NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock({
                                if let updateCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? ConversationMessageTableViewCell {
                                    updateCell.userImageView.image = downloadedImage
                                }
                            })
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
        }
        //cell.clipsToBounds = true
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if cell.respondsToSelector(Selector("setSeparatorInset:")) {
            cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
        }
        if cell.respondsToSelector(Selector("setLayoutMargins:")) {
            cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero
        }
        if cell.respondsToSelector(Selector("setPreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins:")) {
            cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
        }

        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        cell.backgroundView = UIView(frame:cell.frame)
        if(cell.backgroundView?.layer.sublayers?.count > 1){
            cell.backgroundView?.layer.sublayers?.removeAtIndex(0)
        }
        let layer = self.getGradientLayer(indexPath.row)
        cell.backgroundView?.layer.insertSublayer(layer, atIndex: 0)

    }
}
```

And here's the subclass of `UITableViewCell` i have written for the protyped cell.

```
class ConversationMessageTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var userImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var dateLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var userFullNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var messageBodyLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var messageBodyLabelHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code

        userImageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
        userImageView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        userImageView.layer.cornerRadius = (userImageView.frame.height/2)
        userImageView.clipsToBounds = true
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
```

Here's the edited screen shot (I have blackened out the name and faces)

[image: This is what happens]

Help required!

I can see long text not getting messed up,but it only happens with small texts.

Basically, this only happens when i scroll the tableview up and down few times. All the text is displayed properly when tableview loads, but then messes up and then clears out for a while and again messes up.

Comment: Have you added constraint to labels like horizontal spacing?

Comment: Yes it everything is added. Constraints and all are fine. It just overlaps.

Comment: There must be some issues with the constraints. Whats your expected output?

Comment: If constraints were an issue, the storyboard itself shows errors or warnings right? Also while the view loads, it will say "One of the constraints is not needed..........as so on", but I don't see any of it.

Comment: By issues i don't mean warnings or errors. I mean that for e.g Constraints could be added wrongly. Like First label width is x then Second label leading is set x - somevalue

Comment: I have used a horizontal stack view and added the image view, namelabel and datelabel to it and the label to show the multiline text is below it with the bottom constraint, top constraint w.r.t the stackview and the left and right ones. The problem happening is with the lower label and not the ones inside the stackview

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to this problem.
There is an option in story board which says Clear Graphics Context which basically clears the graphics for the label before redrawing it.